# Basic preconditioned gradient descent example

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I'm exploring preconditioned gradient descent using a similar toy problem described in the first part of [Lecture 8: Accelerating SGD with preconditioning and adaptive learning rates](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4787/2019sp/notes/lecture8.pdf).

I have the function $f(x,y) = x^2 + 10\,y^2$ which has a gradient of $[2x, 20y]$.

I know the ideal form of the function is $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ which has a gradient of $[2\,x, 2\,y]$.

How do I solve for the precondition matrix in the equation, $w_{t+1} = w_t - \alpha\,P\,\nabla f(w_t)$, like the first activity box asks? In this case $P$ would just be $[1, \frac{1}{10}]$?

At the bottom of the second page it says: [image]

I'm having trouble understanding how to formally solve for it in variance context described in the answer here [Preconditioning gradient descent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91862/preconditioning-gradient-descent).  I also see in that answer, reference of the third approach w/ $P = [H f(x^*)]^{-1}$.

I am unable to find any other examples walked through online.

Comment: @LmnICE Thanks for the edit, wasn't aware that you can just type latex in directly!

Comment: you're welcome! There are other formatting tricks; you can find them [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help). With LaTeX you can even use a few statements (_e.g._ `\begin{align}`).

Comment: I'm really interested in this question; I'll be checking on it when I have more time. One thing to note - $P = RR^T$ where $R$ is a fixed matrix, so $P$ must be symmetric. This paper might help too - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.04202.pdf

Comment: @Elenchus I actually didn't see the 3 approaches listed at the bottom of the second page which I added into the question. So the 2 approaches in that other answer are definitely legit, but I just need to know how to apply them to this example problem!

Comment: @Quantoisseur I missed that too; nice edit to the question, it's really clear now. I've brushed up a bit on optimisation (I swear I forget how matrices work every time I look away from them) so I'll have a go at an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the hessian is constant $P = H^{-1}$ is optimal (you fully recover Newton's method): $P = H^{-1} = \text{diag}(1/2, 1/20)$. This is equivalent to making the change of variables $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} x'$ and $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{20}} y'$ which gives you the desired $\frac{1}{2} (x'^2 + y'^2)$ form.

As for approach 2, this is just a systematic way of *estimating* the scale of your variables. Get an empirical estimate for the [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) $\Sigma \approx \text{Cov}(x)$. [The answer you referenced](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/343711) shows how $P = \Sigma$ follows from a change of variable and chain-rule.

What distribution do you sample if you want to do approach 2? If you treat your objective function as a negative log-likelihood, then you should be sampling from a normal distribution with $\frac{1}{2} \Sigma^{-1} = \operatorname{diag}(1, 10)$. So you should get $\Sigma = \operatorname{diag}(1/2, 1/20)$. If you were to take many random samples from this distribution and calculate their covariance, you would get the same answer since $\Sigma_{i,j} := \operatorname{E} [(x_i - \mu_i)( x_j - \mu_j)] = \operatorname{Cov}(x)$ (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)).

These approaches are equivalent when your data is normally-distributed and you have a lot of it. In practice, approach 2 is more generally applicable to situations where the Hessian is not constant, but can be somewhat crude.

Automatically computing a dynamic preconditioning matrix is a very well studied topic. Optimization methods that do this are called [Quasi-Newton methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Newton_method).

Comment: Appreciate the answer! I have a question on approach 2. To test, I am sampling along the x and y axes which gives me a covariance matrix (between the two vectors) scaled roughly from $\Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 10 \\
10 & 100
\end{bmatrix}$. Note: Can't be exact as that's not positive definite. I then calculate $L^T = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 10 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$. How do I extract P from this?

Comment: I think you must have been sampling from the wrong distribution. I added a detailed explanation of how to use #2 in this case.

Comment: Ya, I was not using the correct sampling distributions. Could you please explain or link to an explanation of the transformation from the objective function to normal distributions: "If you treat your objective function as a negative log-likelihood, then you should be sampling from a normal distribution"? I see how once you get the covariance matrix it works out to P, but in this case shouldn't we find P to be diag(1, 1/10) like the first method?

Comment: Or are they not equivalent because our data is not normally-distributed?

Comment: Ah, yes. I made a mistake. There should be another L factor in there since dx and dx’ are different. I’ll fix up the answer in a bit

Comment: Ok, I updated this answer and the other answer: should be correct now.

Comment: Thank you for the additional resources and explanations. I think the last piece that I'm missing is how do we know to sample from a normal distribution with $\frac{1}{2}\Sigma^{-1} = \text{diag}(1,10)$?

Comment: Well, in this case there isn't much point in actually sampling and computing the empirical covariance, since you already know it exactly.


In most real-world applications, you won't know the actual distribution of the data, but you will have a dataset of samples from some unknown distribution. This is exactly where this approach is useful.

If you really do just want get random samples from a normal distribution, there are lots of algorithms and libraries that do this. `mvrnorm` in R or `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal` in python for example.

Comment: I understand how to generate and sample from a multivariate normal but don't understand in this case, assuming I don't know the actual distribution, how to sample and where the normal distribution shows up. That's why above I tried to replicate by sampling on the x and y axes which puts me in the right direction as I find the variance of one axis to be 1/100 of the other which is very close, just a square root difference. Is this the correct approach or how should I sample? I'm trying to get a concrete understanding of this as I am going to apply to more complicated functions.

Comment: I also really do appreciate the help and would love to connect on LinkedIn (https://www.linkedin.com/in/coltonfsmith/). I'm working on this as part of a blog project (https://quantoisseur.com/) and will absolutely give credit where it's due for your help here.

Comment: Approach 2 only works for optimizing a log-likelihood, not for optimizing an arbitrary function. When your optimizing a log likelihood for a particular dataset, you can use the empirical covariance of this dataset as $P$, or just normalize your data prior to optimizing the likelihood.

Comment: Okay gotcha, that makes sense especially since the lecture mentions a linear model (implying MLE) as an example.

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly sure you can just use the Hessian, which in this case is $$
2\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 10
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This comes from method 3 (using second-partial derivative information), and possibly also method 1.

The reason we're using the exact matrix here instead of an approximation is because this is a simple case; as noted elsewhere efficiency can be an issue with larger dimensions.
[image: how to make preconditioning efficient]

We've already got a diagonal matrix, so even if we did approximate as suggested it would be the same. Note this matrix also satisfies the criteria of being symmetric and positive semi-definite.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the variance context part. I'm also not certain that it should be the Hessian of the overall function - it could be that it's supposed to be recalculated at each time step using the selected values for the function. The notation in the lecture notes made me think not, but the other answer made me think so. Happy to keep thinking about this

Comment: The hessian of $f(x,y) = x^2 + 10y^2$ is $H = 2
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 10
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The inverse is what you wrote which I see is written in the update equation so it still works out.

Comment: I see that in the other answer you can "approximate the hessian as constant near the minimum" which I guess is what we're doing in this case?

Comment: I meant to write the Hessian itself, got confused looking at your suggestion for P, sorry

Comment: Ah, the hessian is constant in this case so even if you recalculated at all places, it'll be the same! Okay, I'm happy with how to use the hessian now, thank you. I'd still be interested in the variance context as well, as it seems easily generalized to approximations.

Comment: @Quantoisseur Do you have any idea [How can we think of these methods as relating to diagonal preconditioning](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4787/2019sp/notes/lecture8.pdf#page=4) ?

Comment: @Elenchus As for **method 3 (using second-partial derivative information)** , do you mean Adam algorithm ?   If yes, how is the second-partial derivative (or second moment bias) related to hessian ?

Comment: @kevin the Hessian is the matrix of second-partial derivatives. See https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/applications-of-multivariable-derivatives/quadratic-approximations/a/the-hessian

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem that preconditioning tries to solve:

[image]

From this [blog](https://blog.ephorie.de/contagiousness-of-covid-19-part-i-improvements-of-mathematical-fitting-guest-post) (also discussed here on stackexchange: [Fitting SIR model with 2019-nCoV data doesn't conververge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/446712/fitting-sir-model-with-2019-ncov-data-doesnt-conververge))

**Problems:**

- With gradient descent methods you follow a path down-hill. But, your algorithm is often not as smooth as water and doesn't flow straight down in the most efficient way. Instead, often the algorithm will 'over-shoot' and follow an (inefficient) zigzag path.
- Another problem is that the algorithm might have some basic rules to decide when to stop. For instance, deciding to stop when the step sizes are getting very small. However, for that stopping rule, when you are [not looking into the direction of the optimum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/367397) (because you are looking along the slow zigzag path), it might be that your step sizes are small while the optimum is still far away.

(the first problem is about the speed of getting a solution/convergence, the second problem is about the accuracy of the result)

**Methods to 'pre-condition':**

So it would be nice if you could change the scale of the different variables somehow (make them more equal instead of having this valley). You only need to know *how*.

- method 1: use the formula for the problem or some intuition about the problem.

  In your case, the function $f(x,y) = x^2 + 10y^2$, you can compute the scaling/pre-conditioning based on the formula. In the formulation of your reference... $P$ should be a matrix. That is $P$ is not $\left[1,1/10\right]$ but instead $$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/10 \end{bmatrix}$$
  It is the scaling of the variables that is a vector, namely $R = \left[1,\sqrt{1/10}\right]$.

  Without formula, you can use 'intuition'. For instance, you might be having features with widely varying scales. I often just do this. Scale the variables such that the range of the 'expected' solution will be similar for each variable. (In the image below you see this as well. The range of the $R_0$ and $K$ parameter is a lot different)
- method 2: Use the data/variance. I believe that this refers to using a sample distribution of the features (or some other information about the scale of spread). The variance of the features relates to the curvature of the likelihood function ([observed information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observed_information) matrix). Maybe this method is also much the same as 'use intuition'.

  Aside from just looking at the scale of the parameters, it is
  also important to look at the 'variation'. If some parameter is around $1 \, kilometer \pm 0.001 \, kilometer$, then the loss function has more curvature than a parameter around $10 \, meter \pm 2 \, meter$. (you can see this in the image below, the parameter $R_0 \approx 1$ has a larger scale than the $K \approx 0.4$ parameter, but the variation is in a much smaller range)
- method 3: You may not have a formula or intuition like in method 1, but you could compute the Hessian at some point during the descent and adapt the scaling accordingly.

  This method 3 is particularly nice if the problem is not continuous. For instance in the image below you get that the hessian and the scale is varying. Intuitively, the line that the "half-pipe" follows is bended (in the beginning the $K$ parameter has more curvature, but later the $R_0$ parameter). In these cases you can not easily solve problems of convergence by just setting a (single) pre-conditioning from the start, and you need to change it in multiple steps (along the path).

  [image: banana]

Comment: Appreciate the answer!

Comment: I'm trying to solve via approach 2 in the comment on Reid Hayes answer. Could you possibly help?